# read from cap file with ascii output without -z option

Tags: wireshark, tshark

I have been using this script to automatically split a pcap file into single tcp streams:

```
for stream in $(tshark -r $1 -T fields -e tcp.stream | sort -n | uniq)
do
    echo $stream
    tshark -r $1 -w $2/stream-$stream.cap -Y "tcp.stream==$stream"
done
```

now, for each single capture file that represents a stream I can read them with

```
tshark -r somefile.cap
```

but I get this kind of output:

```
1   0.000000   172.18.0.4 → 172.18.0.5   HTTP 386 GET /eureka/apps/delta HTTP/1.1 
    2   0.001457   172.18.0.5 → 172.18.0.4   HTTP 466 HTTP/1.1 200 OK  (application/json)
    3   0.001490   172.18.0.4 → 172.18.0.5   TCP 66 37830 → 8761 [ACK] Seq=321 Ack=401 Win=287 Len=0 TSval=330522 TSecr=330522
...
```

I would like to read it with the same format that you get when you follow a stream using -z, for example

```
tshark -r somefile.pcap -z "follow,http,ascii,172.18.0.6:57238,172.18.0.4:8081"
```

which gives you the same as above, plus

```
===================================================================
Follow: http,ascii
Filter: ((ip.src eq 172.18.0.6 and tcp.srcport eq 57238) and (ip.dst eq 172.18.0.4 and tcp.dstport eq 8081)) or ((ip.src eq 172.18.0.4 and tcp.srcport eq 8081) and (ip.dst eq 172.18.0.6 and tcp.dstport eq 57238))
Node 0: 172.18.0.6:57238
Node 1: 172.18.0.4:8081
821
POST /api/cars?cacheBuster=1511774200847 HTTP/1.1
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImF1dGgiOiJST0xFX0FETUlOLFJPTEVfVVNFUiIsImV4cCI6MTUxMzI1NzU5MX0.xyXj0-7xjluW0jB9y2UGzcZcruADHkgTH_mnTIYsSmggqDW7XIeHC7ftKPmaMjozLhpIGofHAbrXj6TOTQlvXQ
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,it;q=0.8,ru;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
x-forwarded-host: localhost:8080
x-forwarded-proto: http
x-forwarded-prefix: /carapp
x-forwarded-port: 8080
x-forwarded-for: 172.18.0.1
Content-Length: 61
Host: 172.18.0.4:8081
Connection: Keep-Alive
...
```

at the end.

does some option that does this exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like the following would help?

```
tshark -r somefile.pcap -Y "http and (((ip.src eq 172.18.0.6 and tcp.srcport eq 57238) and (ip.dst eq 172.18.0.4 and tcp.dstport eq 8081)) or ((ip.src eq 172.18.0.4 and tcp.srcport eq 8081) and (ip.dst eq 172.18.0.6 and tcp.dstport eq 57238)))" -O http
```

... or a bit more simply, which should accomplish the same thing:

```
tshark -r somefile.pcap -Y "http and (ip.addr eq 172.18.0.6 and tcp.port eq 57238 and ip.addr eq 172.18.0.4 and tcp.port eq 8081)" -O http
```

... or even simpler if you know the TCP stream number associated with this conversation:

```
tshark -r somefile.pcap -Y "http and tcp.stream eq 0" -O http
```

(Here, I've just assumed the stream index is 0.)

Refer to the [`tshark` man page](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) for more information.

Comment: thanks for the insight, none of this worked but you made me realize that I just need to get the "tcp.stream eq 0" of each file (since they are already divided by stream), so with 
`tshark -r stream-6.cap -z "follow,http,ascii,0"`
I can get what I want.